# how to save document and update another which are dependent on each other with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my bid model.

```
const BidSchema = new Schema({
  auctionKey: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Auction",
    required: true
  },
  amount: { type: String, required: true },
  userName: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

And, here is my Auction Model (Notice the relationships between these two models).

```
const AuctionSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  startDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  closeDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  initialBidAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
  bidIncrementAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
  bids: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Bid'
    }
  ]
});
```

When user bids for any auction, I'm saving bid in bids collection and updating auctions collection using mongoose `findOneAndUpdate`.

```
const postBid = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { auctionKey } = req.body;
  const bid = new BidModel(req.body);
  bid.save(error => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Could not post bid." });
    }
  });

  const aucById = await AuctionModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: auctionKey },
    { $push: { bids: bid } }
  ).exec((error: any, auction: IAuction) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Could not post bid." });
    } else {
      res.status(201).json({ bid });
    }
  });
};
```

For any reason if any of these two (`save` bid and `findOneAndUpdate`) throws any error I want nothing to be saved into database. I mean to say either they should save and update or nothing should be done on database.

I have tried using mongoose session and transaction but got this error.

```
 MongoError: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.
```

Is there any way to work out in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you can just delete created document in:

```
.exec((error: any, auction: IAuction) => {
    if (error) {
       // here, by using .deleteOne()
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Could not post bid." });
    }
```

Or just change structure of your code, so only when two are successfully created, they will be saved and response will be sent.

Comment: I can delete like you said, but I’m looking for other solutions. When you say change the structure of the code, what do you mean ? Can yuh provide an example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can do that using try/catch, so if some error occured, you are thow an error and send response with 500 code. Like this: ```const aucById = await AuctionModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: auctionKey },
    { $push: { bids: bid } }
  ).exec((error: any, auction: IAuction) => {
    if (error) throw new Error();
  }); ``` and then catch it. If there is no error in the end of try, send response with 200 and save all changes